# When I try to do routing I get a parse error in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, routes

I published the web site and uploaded it to FTP (ASP.NET Web Forms C#).

I use routing in the project and this is my routing page's code (I only write 1):

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
public void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("HomePage", "HomePage", "~/Views/Default.aspx");
}
```

And my folders and pages are as follows:

[image]

The code of the Default.aspx page outside the Views folder:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("/Views/");
}
```

When I try to enter mywebsite.com and enter the site, I get the following error:

[image]

But when I try to enter mywebsite.com/HomePage it works. I want to go to the main page when I write the site name directly. Where do I make mistakes?

I forgot to add: It's working on local btw. But doesn't work on FTP.

Answer (score 0):

You have your routing configured incorrectly. The the home page URL is setup as `HomePage` instead of an empty string (`/HomePage`).

```
routes.MapPageRoute("HomePage", "HomePage", "~/Views/Default.aspx");
```

Change that to (`/`):

```
routes.MapPageRoute("HomePage", "", "~/Views/Default.aspx");
```

Also, **delete** your "Default.aspx page outside of Views folder". That is going to conflict with your routing and (even worse) it will cause an HTTP 302 redirect to your home page. An HTTP 302 redirect returned from the request tells the user's browser to make **a second request** to your server, which is bad for both performance and SEO reasons.

Given that your `/HomePage` URL is working correctly, the above changes should fix your problem.